# How can I properly create a contenteditable "Font Tester" type editor with CSS classes applied by JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, contenteditable

I've created a website to share the fonts I've designed, and I'm trying to incorporate a "Type Tester" so that people can interact with the fonts before downloading them. I've scoured the internet for how to do this, and pre-made plugins/solutions mostly seem overly heavy (a la full-on type editors) for my purposes. Examples similar to what I'm trying to accomplish can be found at the font pages at Type Supply, or any font page at MyFonts.

**I want to give users the ability to:**

1. **Select the font.**
2. **Select the font size.**
3. **Select the font weight/style.**

Now, **[I've come close to a working solution on my website](http://fourthfloorfoundry.com/warehouse.html#tryit)**, but it has a curious problem: styles can only be edited a couple of times before it stops working. This is especially odd, because I was able to put together **[a simpler version of the type editor on a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thundernixon/BsyuK/)**, which seems to have no problems with unlimited style changes. The basic HTML I'm manipulating is:

```
  <span contenteditable="true"> 
       <span class="fontselect fontsize fontweight textfield">Click here to try it!</span> 
  </span>
```

With three select menus, similar to this:

```
  <select class="" data-native-menu="false" id="font-family-select" name="typeface"> 
       <option value="georgia" >Georgia</option> 
       <option value="couriernew">Courier New</option> 
       <option value="hevetica" selected="selected">Helvetica</option> 
  </select>
```

...and JQuery that adds & removes CSS classes according to what is selected.

Can any of you figure out what I'm doing wrong on the version on my actual website? Sorry if the problem is obvious – it's hard to know whether I just need another set of eyeballs on my syntax, or whether my problem is something larger.

Thank you so much for any help/advice/comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved by this way. Ugly, but works.

1. Create `changeStyle` function.
2. Add `id="try"` to span  **Click here to try it!**.
3. Add to all select combobox `onchange="changeStyle()"` event

   ```
   <script>
      function changeStyle(){
               family= $("#font-family-select").val();
               size=$("#font-size-select").val();
               weight=$("#font-weight-select").val();

               $("#try").removeClass().addClass("fontselect fontsize fontweight " + family + " " + size + " " + weight);
       } </script>
   ```

> ...
>
> <span **id="try"** class="fontselect fontsize fontweight de 64
>   textfield">Click here to try it!</span>
>   ...
>
> <select **onchange="changeStyle()"**
>
> <select **onchange="changeStyle()"**
>
> <select **onchange="changeStyle()"**
>
> ...

Comment: So bummed I can't upvote your answer without 15 reps myself, but I will come back to upvote this the day I make it to 15. 

Thank you so much for taking the time to figure this out and lend a hand!

Comment: Ohhhh, crap, wait – it's not _quite_ working yet. It could just be my implementation of it, though ... 

The select menus change the CSS styles quite well if the editable text is left alone, or simply changed a bit. However, if the text is entirely backspaced, then something new is written in, the select menus don't seem to work (tested in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox). 

I'll update again if I can figure out that the bug lies in my syntax. 

Still, thanks for making it work better than before! I'll get it eventually...